# Import of Decompose for Kotlin Compose (Desktop) doesn't work, how can I solved it?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, import

I've actually an issue with the usage of Arkivanov Decompose (https://github.com/arkivanov/Decompose)

And when I've tried to use it in my project with Intellij, but that doesn't seem to work, so I've tried to write the import manually, but it doesn't work too. I've searched for a long times if I've made an error in the build.gradle, but haven't found anything.

To sum up, this import doesn't work when I try to use the Decompose in my projet, so does anybody can help me ?

I've import it in my build.gradle like this :

```
kotlin {
    jvm {
        jvmToolchain(11)
        withJava()
    }
    sourceSets {
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
                implementation("com.arkivanov.essenty:lifecycle:1.1.0")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.0")
                implementation("com.arkivanov.decompose:decompose:2.0.0")
                implementation("com.arkivanov.decompose:extensions-compose-jetbrains:2.0.0")
            }
        }
        val jvmTest by getting
    }
}
```

And for information I used :

SDK : Amazon Correto 11.0.18

Kotlin : 1.8.21

And my Gradle use SDK 11 (I don't know if it's the version, I only found that in Intellij)

Comment: It appears that you have specified a wrong version of Decompose. Version 2.0.0 doesn't exist yet, the latest version is 2.0.0-alpha-02.

Comment: Oh okay ! It seems to work greatly better, Intellij just colorized in grey my annotation @OptIn with the ExperimentalDecomposeApi, but thanks for the help !