# How to patch NoSuchMethodError from Compose Multi-platform (Desktop) and Decompose?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

I've posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76329546) today to solve a problem with the installation of Decompose After that I've tried to implement the decompose desktop example, but I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean androidx.compose.runtime.Composer.changedInstance(java.lang.Object)'
```

I've tried to check if I've not just passed a bad parameter or use a bad import but I haven't found anything.

The part of my `NavHostComponent` to render:

```
/**
 * Renders screen as per request
 */
@OptIn(ExperimentalDecomposeApi::class)
@Composable
override fun render() {
    Children(
        stack = stack,
        animation = stackAnimation(fade() + scale()),
    ) {
        it.instance.render()
    }
}

private sealed class ScreenConfig : Parcelable {
    object MainView : ScreenConfig()
}
```

My main with the func I used in :

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalDecomposeApi::class)
fun main() {
    val windowState = WindowState()
    val lifecycle = LifecycleRegistry()
    val root = runOnMainThreadBlocking { NavHostComponent(DefaultComponentContext(lifecycle)) }

    singleWindowApplication(
        state = windowState,
        title = "MyProject",
    ) {
        LifecycleController(lifecycle, windowState)

        DecomposeDesktopExampleTheme { root.render() }
    }
}

private inline fun <T: Any> runOnMainThreadBlocking(crossinline block: () -> T): T {
    lateinit var result: T
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait { result = block() }
    return result
}
```

I've compared the structure of my code with the structure of the decompose desktop example, but that doesn't seem to be that.
I've checked if my stack was good or if I've made some errors but I haven't seen anything in my code.

Why do I get this error and how do I get rid of it?

Edit :

I put here the full stack trace :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean androidx.compose.runtime.Composer.changedInstance(java.lang.Object)'
at com.arkivanov.decompose.extensions.compose.jetbrains.stack.animation.StackAnimatorKt$plus$1.invoke(StackAnimator.kt:56)
at com.arkivanov.decompose.extensions.compose.jetbrains.stack.animation.SimpleStackAnimation.Child(SimpleStackAnimation.kt:21)
at com.arkivanov.decompose.extensions.compose.jetbrains.stack.animation.AbstractStackAnimation.invoke(AbstractStackAnimation.kt:40)
at com.arkivanov.decompose.extensions.compose.jetbrains.stack.ChildrenKt.Children(Children.kt:29)
at com.arkivanov.decompose.extensions.compose.jetbrains.stack.ChildrenKt.Children(Children.kt:45)
at model.navigation.NavHostComponent.render(NavHostComponent.kt:58)
at MainKt$main$1$1.invoke(Main.kt:24)
at MainKt$main$1$1.invoke(Main.kt:24)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at view.theme.ThemeKt$DecomposeDesktopExampleTheme$1$1.invoke(Theme.kt:38)
at view.theme.ThemeKt$DecomposeDesktopExampleTheme$1$1.invoke(Theme.kt:37)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.material.SurfaceKt$Surface$1.invoke(Surface.kt:134)
at androidx.compose.material.SurfaceKt$Surface$1.invoke(Surface.kt:117)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.material.SurfaceKt.Surface-F-jzlyU(Surface.kt:114)
at view.theme.ThemeKt$DecomposeDesktopExampleTheme$1.invoke(Theme.kt:35)
at view.theme.ThemeKt$DecomposeDesktopExampleTheme$1.invoke(Theme.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme_desktopKt.PlatformMaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.desktop.kt:26)
at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:82)
at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:81)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.material.TextKt.ProvideTextStyle(Text.kt:265)
at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:81)
at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:80)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt.MaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.kt:72)
at view.theme.ThemeKt.DecomposeDesktopExampleTheme(Theme.kt:29)
at MainKt$main$1.invoke(Main.kt:24)
at MainKt$main$1.invoke(Main.kt:21)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.ui.awt.ComposeWindow$setContent$5.invoke(ComposeWindow.desktop.kt:126)
at androidx.compose.ui.awt.ComposeWindow$setContent$5.invoke(ComposeWindow.desktop.kt:125)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.ui.awt.ComposeWindowDelegate$setContent$3$1.invoke(ComposeWindowDelegate.desktop.kt:146)
at androidx.compose.ui.awt.ComposeWindowDelegate$setContent$3$1.invoke(ComposeWindowDelegate.desktop.kt:145)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.ui.awt.ComposeWindowDelegate$setContent$3.invoke(ComposeWindowDelegate.desktop.kt:142)
at androidx.compose.ui.awt.ComposeWindowDelegate$setContent$3.invoke(ComposeWindowDelegate.desktop.kt:141)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.ui.ComposeScene$setContent$5.invoke(ComposeScene.skiko.kt:371)
at androidx.compose.ui.ComposeScene$setContent$5.invoke(ComposeScene.skiko.kt:370)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:177)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.Wrapper_skikoKt$setContent$2$1.invoke(Wrapper.skiko.kt:47)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.Wrapper_skikoKt$setContent$2$1.invoke(Wrapper.skiko.kt:46)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:248)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.Wrapper_skikoKt.provide(Wrapper.skiko.kt:61)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.Wrapper_skikoKt.access$provide(Wrapper.skiko.kt:1)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.Wrapper_skikoKt$setContent$2.invoke(Wrapper.skiko.kt:46)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.Wrapper_skikoKt$setContent$2.invoke(Wrapper.skiko.kt:45)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ActualJvm_jvmKt.invokeComposable(ActualJvm.jvm.kt:73)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3248)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3238)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3238)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime(Composer.kt:3173)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:587)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime(Recomposer.kt:950)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:519)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.Wrapper_skikoKt.setContent(Wrapper.skiko.kt:45)
at androidx.compose.ui.ComposeScene.setContent$ui(ComposeScene.skiko.kt:367)
at androidx.compose.ui.ComposeScene.setContent$ui$default(ComposeScene.skiko.kt:346)
at androidx.compose.ui.awt.ComposeLayer$setContent$3$1.invoke(ComposeLayer.desktop.kt:435)
at androidx.compose.ui.awt.ComposeLayer$setContent$3$1.invoke(ComposeLayer.desktop.kt:434)
at androidx.compose.ui.awt.ComposeLayer.catchExceptions(ComposeLayer.desktop.kt:109)
at androidx.compose.ui.awt.ComposeLayer.access$catchExceptions(ComposeLayer.desktop.kt:87)
at androidx.compose.ui.awt.ComposeLayer$setContent$3.invoke(ComposeLayer.desktop.kt:434)
at androidx.compose.ui.awt.ComposeLayer$setContent$3.invoke(ComposeLayer.desktop.kt:433)
at androidx.compose.ui.awt.ComposeLayer.initContent(ComposeLayer.desktop.kt:449)
at androidx.compose.ui.awt.ComposeLayer.access$initContent(ComposeLayer.desktop.kt:87)
at androidx.compose.ui.awt.ComposeLayer$ComponentImpl.addNotify(ComposeLayer.desktop.kt:226)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2800)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4783)
at androidx.compose.ui.awt.ComposeWindowDelegate$_pane$1.addNotify(ComposeWindowDelegate.desktop.kt:80)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2800)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4783)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2800)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4783)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2800)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4783)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JRootPane.addNotify(JRootPane.java:733)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2800)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.addNotify(Window.java:786)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.addNotify(Frame.java:490)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.pack(Window.java:824)
at androidx.compose.ui.util.Windows_desktopKt.makeDisplayable(Windows.desktop.kt:160)
at androidx.compose.ui.window.Window_desktopKt$Window$11$1.invoke(Window.desktop.kt:392)
at androidx.compose.ui.window.Window_desktopKt$Window$11$1.invoke(Window.desktop.kt:385)
at androidx.compose.ui.window.AwtWindow_desktopKt$AwtWindow$3.invoke(AwtWindow.desktop.kt:83)
at androidx.compose.ui.window.AwtWindow_desktopKt$AwtWindow$3.invoke(AwtWindow.desktop.kt:81)
at androidx.compose.ui.util.UpdateEffect_desktopKt$UpdateEffect$2$performUpdate$1.invoke(UpdateEffect.desktop.kt:59)
at androidx.compose.ui.util.UpdateEffect_desktopKt$UpdateEffect$2$performUpdate$1.invoke(UpdateEffect.desktop.kt:55)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2140)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:134)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:130)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:130)
at androidx.compose.ui.util.UpdateEffect_desktopKt$UpdateEffect$2.invoke$performUpdate(UpdateEffect.desktop.kt:55)
at androidx.compose.ui.util.UpdateEffect_desktopKt$UpdateEffect$2.invoke(UpdateEffect.desktop.kt:64)
at androidx.compose.ui.util.UpdateEffect_desktopKt$UpdateEffect$2.invoke(UpdateEffect.desktop.kt:47)
at androidx.compose.runtime.DisposableEffectImpl.onRemembered(Effects.kt:81)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl$RememberEventDispatcher.dispatchRememberObservers(Composition.kt:1091)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.applyChangesInLocked(Composition.kt:818)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.applyChanges(Composition.kt:839)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime(Recomposer.kt:978)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:519)
at androidx.compose.ui.window.Application_desktopKt$awaitApplication$2$1$2.invokeSuspend(Application.desktop.kt:219)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: This looks like a binary compatibility issue. Even though Compose shouldn't have breaking changes, sometimes this may happen. Check versions of Decompose and Compose.

Comment: First thanks for the response, I've checked versions of Decompose and Compose, Decompose seems to be on version "2.0.0-alpha-02" and Compose on "1.4.0". I didn't find anything about uncompatibility, does I need to downgrade Compose version to 1.3.0 ?

Comment: It should work fine with Compose 1.4.0. A full stack trace could shed some light. Or, if you happen to have a reproducer, please file an issue at https://github.com/arkivanov/Decompose/issues

Comment: Ok, I see, I have add the full stack trace to the post, it will be better with that, another thanks for your replies !

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a bug in Compose, however it's not clear why it does work locally in Decompose tests. A reproducer would be good to investigate. Meantime, could you please try Decompose version `2.0.0-experimental-compose-alpha-02`, instead of `2.0.0-alpha.02` which you are using currently?

Comment: Using the `2.0.0-experimental-compose-alpha-02` instead of `2.0.0-alpha.02` just create me an error when the JVM try to compile, 
`Execution failed for task ':compileKotlinJvm'.`. That tell me he cannot find decompose with the version, it has looked on Google repo, maven and the maven from JetBrains, I will try to include a reproducer during the day.

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake, the correct version is `2.0.0-compose-experimental-alpha-02`. A reproducer would be also helpful.